# Open source deployment manager for windows 10 applications, files and database?

Tags: windows, software-development

I have a system which currently consists of

- .NET application
- batch files
- MS SQL server database

This system is deployed in 20 laptops with Windows 10 OS. Everytime there is a new release/update of the system, we would update the system in each laptops by copying the required files to a thumb drive and working on each laptops one-by-one. If there was a new stored procedure/function, we would of course have to execute them in each laptop's SQL Server.

This process is tiring and error-prone. I am trying to look for an automation tool that can help me do all this. The requirements would look something like this:

1. When each laptop is connected to the release server in a local network, the tool would scan the release server for files that needs to be updated.
2. The tool would then scan each laptops for the version of the files and if the version does not match the one in release server, it would replace them accordingly.
3. The tool would also scan SQL server database objects (tables, functions, stored procedure, etc...) for differences between each laptop's database and the release server's database and execute required scripts to update the objects.
4. If the file/database objects does not exist, the tool would add them in or execute relevant scripts accordingly.

I could write my own script/program to do this but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Some colleagues have recommended me Microsoft's SCCM but I want to use a non-Windows Server OS to do the deployment and also, I'm preferring to go open-source.

Answer (score 3):

No really familiar with Windows Platform in this area, but hopefully I can answer in best effort. Love the CLR ecosystem though. Would interested to know more deployment/integration workflow that work for Desktop app and Web Development

### 1. Write You Own

If you would love to write own script, I think should build on Microsoft supported tools like [OneGet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/packagemanagement/2015/05/05/10-things-about-oneget-that-are-completely-different-than-you-think/) and [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)

### 2. Tools (Free version available)

- [PDQ Deploy](https://www.adminarsenal.com/compare/)
- [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/purchase)
- Popular Chef, Puppet, Ansible or SaltStack, would be what you want, basically, it still need to write configuration to deploy apps, DB etc, and them support more than one platform extensively.
- [Spiceworks might able to do this too](https://www.spiceworks.com)

### 3. Enterprise Grade

[Goverlan](http://www.goverlan.com/online-store.php)

Comment: I don't mind writing configuration as long as I don't have to write it everytime I need to deploy my updates. Chef looks promising. Thanks!